# Create bigquery table using google cloud deployment manager YAML file

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to create a big query table using the deployment manager by following YAML file :

**imports:**

```
- path: schema.txt
```

**resources:**

```
- name: test
  type: bigquery.v2.table
  properties:
    datasetId: test_dt
    tableReference:
       datasetId: test_dt
       projectId: test_dev
       tableId: test
    schema:
       fields: {{ imports["schema.txt"] }}
```

However, when I try to give the table schema definition via .txt file I get a parsing error. If I give the schema definition instead of .txt file then the script runs successfully. This method of importing the text file is given in the google cloud help. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

I think the way the deployment manager is formatting the contents of the .txt file might be incorrect. A good way to debug this would be to collect HTTP request traces and comparing the difference between the two requests.

Answer (score 0):

this is yaml we could get working using nested or repeated field in bigquery deployment manager.

```
# Example of the BigQuery (dataset and table) template usage.
#
# Replace `<FIXME:my_account@email.com>` with your account email.

imports:
  - path: templates/bigquery/bigquery_dataset.py
    name: bigquery_dataset.py
  - path: templates/bigquery/bigquery_table.py
    name: bigquery_table.py

resources:
  - name: dataset_name_here
    type: bigquery_dataset.py
    properties:
      name: dataset_name_here
      location: US
      access:
        - role: OWNER
          userByEmail: my_account@email.com

  - name: table_name_here
    type: bigquery_table.py
    properties:
      name: table_name_here
      datasetId: $(ref.dataset_name_here.datasetId)
      timePartitioning:
        properties:       
          field:
            type: DAY
      schema:
        - name: column1 
          type: STRUCT
          fields:
            - name: column2
              type: string

        - name: test1
          type: RECORD
          mode: REPEATED

          fields:
            - name: test2
              type: string
```

Answer (score 0):

**Sample YAML for Creating View in BigQuery using Deployment manager**:

**Note:** This YAML also shows how to create partitioning(_PARTITIONTIME) on a table (hello_table)

```
# Example of the BigQuery (dataset and table) template usage.
# Replace `<FIXME:my_account@email.com>` with your account email.

imports:
  - path: templates/bigquery/bigquery_dataset.py
    name: bigquery_dataset.py
  - path: templates/bigquery/bigquery_table.py
    name: bigquery_table.py

resources:
  - name: dataset_name
    type: bigquery_dataset.py
    properties:
      name: dataset_name
      location: US
      access:
        - role: OWNER
          userByEmail: my_account@email.com

  - name: hello
    type: bigquery_table.py
    properties:
      name: hello_table
      datasetId: $(ref.dataset_name.datasetId)
      timePartitioning:
        type: DAY

      schema:
      - name: partner_id
        type: STRING
  - name: view_step
    type: bigquery_table.py
    properties:
      name: hello_view
      datasetId: $(ref.dataset_name.datasetId)
      view:
        query: select partner_id from `project_name.dataset_name.hello_table`
        useLegacySql: False
```